# Large numbers of warnings generated by suspected JDBC driver issue using Oracle 19c

Tags: java, oracle, java-17, oracle19c, oracle-aq

**Note: Oracle has now released a fix for this issue. See in comments below.**

**Overview**

We are getting warnings in our database logs that seem to be caused by the following statements:

```
1) BEGIN  :1  := sys.dbms_aqjms.getDBCompatMajorVersion;  :2  := sys.dbms_aqjms.getDBCompatMinorVersion;  END;
```

and

```
2) BEGIN :1  := sys.dbms_aqjms.getMaxIdentifierLength; END;
```

These statements are not being issued by our code but instead by libraries that we are using.

These libraries are:

- Oracle AQ: com.oracle.database.messaging:aqapi-jakarta:23.2.1.0 JDBC
- JDBC driver: com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc11:21.9.0.0

Our Java software is running on Java version 17 against an Oracle 19c Database.

**The messages**

Almost 3 million messages are created which is likely to be a performance issue. They contain the following:

```
Application: JDBC Thin Client Action
WARNING: too many parse errors, count=2974461 SQL hash=0x510bc69c
PARSE ERROR: ospid=6269, error=6550 for statement:
```

Are there any known compatibility problems between the JDBC driver com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc11:21.9.0.0 and Oracle 19c?

Anything else that could be causing this? How do we go about resolving it?

Comment: The same question is here https://community.oracle.com/mosc/discussion/4553502/oracle-19c-warnings-with-jdbc-driver-and-aq-client-on-java-17 since I do not have Oracle account, I cannot see answers... How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is definitely compatibility issues. Since the mentioned procedures are not available in 19c.

- sys.dbms_aqjms.getDBCompatMajorVersion
- sys.dbms_aqjms.getDBCompatMinorVersion
- sys.dbms_aqjms.getMaxIdentifierLength

Please find the screenshot below

[image]

**Edit1**:- Also to add these procedures are available in 23C.Hence the libraries you mentioned are compatible with 23C.

**Resolution**:-You can either upgrade the database to 23c or use libraries compatible with 19c.

Comment: Unfortunately, Oracle cannot be upgraded yet in our case, library aqapi-jakarta does not exist in older versions for jdk17 and spring boot 3... Any suggestions?

Comment: check this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.messaging/aqapi/19.3.0.0

Comment: Oracle has now released a fix for this. 

<oracle.aqapi.version>23.3.0.0</oracle.aqapi.version>           
 
<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle.database.messaging</groupId>
<artifactId>aqapi-jakarta</artifactId>
<version>${oracle.aqapi.version}</version>
</dependency>